# SQL trigger not compiling

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, triggers

iam using Oracle sqldeveloper 3.2.20 and oracleXE112 as my DB. Iam trying to create a trigger, but keep getting this error

```
Error(2,13): PLS-00357: Table,View Or Sequence reference 'SPRAVCA.REGION_ID_REGION' not allowed in this context
```

I have table SPRAVCA with foreign key REGION_ID_REGION that is linked to primary key ID_REGION in table REGION. I have attribute pocet_sp that represents number of SPRAVCA entities that are assigned to specific REGION entity.
My script lookes like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER calc_poc_sp
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
ON SPRAVCA
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (SPRAVCA.REGION_ID_REGION) = (REGION.ID_REGION) THEN
NEW.POCET_SP := OLD.POCET_SP + 1;
END IF;
END calc_poc_sp;
```

I want to create a trigger, that will automaticly increment pocet_sp in REGION entity if any SPRAVCA with matching foregin key will be created. Thanks a lot in advance !

Comment: is SPRAVCA.REGION_ID_REGION a sequence by any chance..??

Comment: The trigger deals with inserts and updates of table SPRAVCA. You have qualifiers :NEW and :OLD for the record in question available, but no qualifiers SPRAVCA and REGION. (Also notice that NEW and OLD need a colon.)

Comment: nope, i thought SPRAVCA is representing table SPRAVCA and .REGION_ID_REGION its attribute, so i just put that in an equation. I am assuming that it will automaticly loop through all region attributes and find a match, but most likely, iam wrong

Comment: This is wrong syntax and code...i am assuming you are not a PLSQL developer so please consult one. else you may be going round and round in this and you wouldnt have a clue where u are going..

Comment: You are right, iam new to PLSQL and probably missing the basics. As for now, i dont know anyone skilled enough (except my lecturer that is pregnant and have no time for consultations right now xD), so self study, documentation and this wonderfull site is the only option left (without spending money, and as a student of university, iam kinda low on them :D)

Comment: ostiepoK..i can understand your problem. Contact me later with ur complete use case in case you are not able to complete this..My conact is in my profile. you will find my fb profile there...i will help you the max i can..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In oracle:

```
IF (SPRAVCA.REGION_ID_REGION) = (REGION.ID_REGION) THEN
```

doesnt work. This is not like java or any other programming language. here the sequence object is an object which has 2 methods that can access the value. CURRVAL and NEXT VAL.

NEXTVAL will increment your current value and retrieve the incremented value. but CURRVAL will retireve value that is currently.

Unfortunately. i have experienced that the CURRVAL generally doesnt work untill the NEXTVAL hasnt been called on the sequence in the same Connection session.

Please specify use case as in why u need to check the current value of the Sequence.

Still a corrected version will be:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER calc_poc_sp
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
ON SPRAVCA
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
VAL_CHECK REGION.ID_REGION%TYPE;
CURSOR REGION IS SELECT * FROM REGION;
BEGIN
--
--    SELECT SPRAVCA.REGION_ID_REGION.CURRVAL INTO VAL_CHECK FROM DUAL;

SELECT REGION_ID_REGION INTO VAL_CHECK FROM SPRAVCA <ADD YOUR WHERE CLAUSE SO THAT ONLY 1 ROW IS RETURNED>;
--I have added a loop statement so that u can iterate through all the values of the region table. If you dont want to loop then add a where clause where you see the REGION cursor being defined.
FOR 1 IN REGION LOOP
IF (VAL_CHECK) = (REGION.ID_REGION) THEN
--
NEW.POCET_SP := OLD.POCET_SP + 1;
--
END IF;
END LOOP;
END calc_poc_sp;
```

Please see the syntax as i do not have a DB access as of now.

Also a question:

***Where have you defined what is REGION in your trigger. This will be an error as you have not defined it.***

Comment: Thanks a lot, REGION is table with attributes ID_REGION and POCET_SP. I assumed that if i put it like REGION.ATTRIBUTE i will get the attribute value from region table. I havent defined it anywhere in my trigger

Comment: let me update the code then..i will be doing that based on assumptions and then u may correct it as per need.

Comment: So, i think i made a progress, here is my code ->
[link](http://pastebin.com/s1yC18vc)
The problem is i get an error `Error(10,26): PLS-00357: Table,View Or Sequence reference 'REGION.ID_REGION' not allowed in this context`

Comment: change the line:

IF (VAL_CHECK) = (REGION.ID_REGION) THEN

to 

IF (VAL_CHECK) = (I.ID_REGION) THEN

Comment: did it, err dissapeared, but now iam getting `Error(12,1): PLS-00201: identifier 'NEW.POCET_SP' must be declared`

**EDIT Ive changed NEW.POCET_SP := OLD.POCET_SP + 1; to i.POCET_SP := i.POCET_SP + 1; And finally, it is compiling ! Thanks a lot